# How to turn off Etag with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, etag

One of my friend says, etags on off mode for speed up page loading. How to off etags with htaccess?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To unset Etags use 3 lines below:

```
Header unset Pragma
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
```

But, to increase page loading speed, my advice is YSlow.
perfect tool & Yslow recommends to use Etags instead of setting off.

Comment: I put these both at .htaccess and apache conf, and etag still exists after restarting apache 2.2

Comment: @John. Did you check your server configuration to allow you to change Headers in htaccess or AllowOverride setting is on ?

Comment: I believe YSlow actually recommends not having ETags on if your site has more than one server.

Comment: Alex W.'s note is totally right. i didn't know that. thank you. http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

Comment: Also keep in mind ETags can be used to track users; and many users don't want the risk.

Answer (score 5):

Putting the following in your .htaccess should do the trick.

```
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
```

Note: Disabling etags only helps if you are hosting the same content from more than 1 server (such as when using a cluster or CDN). Take a look at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) or [yahoo best practices](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags) for more information.

Comment: Also keep in mind ETags can be used to track users; and many users don't want the risk.