# How Do I Configure eTags?

Tags: .htaccess, etag, litespeed

Using ySlow, it recommends that I use eTags. I never heard of them before today. The question is now, how do I configure eTags?

I just spent the last 2 hours trying to figure this out. I tried adding various recommended scripts to my .htaccess file, but with no luck. ySlow keeps complaining...

My site is a secure site(https) on a litespeed web server. I seen some say you can't configure eTags on a litespeed web server. Is this true?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note (2021-05-14) :

While historically there has been somewhat valid reasons to disable ETags - mainly pushed by Yahoo serving things from server farms and unable to implement ETags properly across all servers - **ETags should not be disabled by default** and chances are Yahoo's problems do not apply to you.

---

I think you're supposed to *disable* ETags, not turn them on.

Try this:

```
Header unset Pragma
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
```

References:

[How to turn off Etag with htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705441/how-to-off-etag-with-htaccess)

http://davidwalsh.name/yslow-htaccess

Comment: I added that to my htaccess, but it doesn't seem to do anything. Yslow is still complaining.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe your apache doesn't let you change it in your htaccess then. I wouldn't worry too much about it, it's not worth blindly following what Yslow tells you unless there is a real problem IMO.

Comment: Use ySlow as a bookmark rather the browser extension is seems to get messed up with the browser cache therefor is not so accurate.

Answer (score 14):

Or, I don't know... Properly set them without the piece that makes them unique to a server.

`FileETag MTime Size`

I understand that it's easier to just tell people to not bother. But there is a *lot* of misinformation out there about ETags. They're not perfect, but can be handy when configured correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the snarky tone but I just read, "However, most of the websites that we tested don't bother configuring their ETags, so a simpler solution is to turn off ETags entirely[...]" right after an explanation about how to properly configure them. One of those moments where I felt like Mugatu screaming about taking crazy pills.

Comment: This became the default value in Apache 2.4. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#fileetag

Answer (score 6):

## Using `.htaccess` to configure ETag response

The OP is specifically asking about configuring etags on a [Litespeed web server](https://www.litespeedtech.com/), but anywhere `.htaccess` can be used, [the method(s)](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#FileETag) *should* remain the same.

### Simple

```
FileETag All
```

This sets the response etag, for all files, calculated from all three possible components:

> **INode**
>  The file's [i-node number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) will be included in the calculation
> **MTime**
>  The date and time the file was last modified will be included
> **Size**
>  The number of bytes in the file will be included

*i.e.* Setting

> **All**
>  All available fields will be used. This is equivalent to:
>  `FileETag INode MTime Size`

*e.g.* Our response might be something like `ETag:"a020a81-1dd-55073fdbf86fe"`

### Specific

`FileETag INode`,
`FileETag MTime`,
`FileETag Size`,
`FileETag INode MTime`,
`FileETag INode Size` or
`FileETag MTime Size` may also be set.

### Omitted

```
FileETag None
```

> **None**
> If a document is file-based, no ETag field will be included in the response

### Targeted

Use of [the FilesMatch directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#FilesMatch) allows us to set different rules for different files.