# How to turn off Etags from a CDN Js file using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, yslow

I tested my site using yslow and I got Grade B in Configure Entity tags.
I tried below condition in .htaccess and my site's Etags are removed, but not from JS included by CDN like validate.min.js

```
Header unset Pragma
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
```

Here is the image,

[image: Yslow Etags]

How to configure etags from Validate plugin from CDN.

It can be possible duplicate of [How to off Etag with htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705441/how-to-off-etag-with-htaccess) except that here I am getting problem with js included by CDN.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is: you can't. Configurations like the ETags can only be controlled by the host, in this cast the CDN.

I think it's safe to not worry about this for your site. Loading that JS from a CDN is already a win, and this CDN is correctly supporting top performance rules like minification, gzip compression, and future expiration dates.